# Learning Rails 3.0 - Migration Help - belongsTo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I'm working on a photo gallery app. Photo has a belongsTo relationship to Album (Album has_many realtionship to Photo) How do I create the migration that adds this relationship to the database correctly? I have tried  - rails generate add_album_to_photo but that comes through as an empty migration. I could use a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming tables `albums` and `photos` exist already, all you have to do is add a column `album_id` to your `photos` table:

```
class AddAlbumToPhoto < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :photos, :album_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :photos, :album_id
  end
end
```

Or:

```
class AddAlbumToPhoto < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :photos do |t|
      t.references :album
    end
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :photos do |t|
      t.remove :album_id
    end
  end
end
```

Or if you insist on generating the code:

```
rails g migration add_album_to_photo album_id:integer
```

Comment: Is it ok if the generation command produced code like the first example in a Rails 3.0 project?

Comment: Yes, both are fine in a Rails 3 project.